# {"Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got Integer. Path 'id', line 1, position 9."}

Tags: vb.net, json.net, dataset

Receiving below error on deserializing json to dataset.

```
Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got Integer. Path 'id', line 1, position 9
```

Json Retrieved : `{"id":130,"type":"general","setup":"test?","punchline":"test."}`

My Code

```
    Dim wc As New WebClient
    Try

        Dim res As String
        For i = 0 To 5
            res =  wc.DownloadString("https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke")

            Dim jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res)

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            ds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataSet)(res)

            MsgBox(ds.Tables.Count)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
```

Comment: Create a Class `Joke`  with properties  `id`,`type`,`setup` and `punchline`.  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Joke)(res)` and then add it to `List<Joke>` in each iteration

Comment: You should probably use a `Dictionary<int, class>`, using the `Id` of the JSON response as the Key, so you avoid adding the same object twice, in case you get a duplicate.

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar, if i have to convert it to list then i can use this right!! Dim jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(res).Root.ToList()

Comment: The API endpoint is returning a Single Record. u have to add each record to the list object after deserializing instead of converting it to a list every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [Akshay Gaonkar commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67935184/unexpected-json-token-when-reading-datatable-expected-startarray-got-integer#comment120077138_67935184), you can give Newtonsoft.Json a class, named, say, `Joke`, to deserialise with. You can get around the mismatch of uppercase/lowercase initial letter naming conventions by decorating the properties with `<JsonProperty("nameInTheJson")>`.

Instead of deserializing the data into a datatable inside a dataset, you could keep it simple and create a `List(Of Joke)`.

This is for a console application:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Module Program

    Class Joke
        <JsonProperty("id")>
        Property Id As Integer

        <JsonProperty("type")>
        Property Type As String

        <JsonProperty("setup")>
        Property Setup As String

        <JsonProperty("punchline")>
        Property Punchline As String

    End Class

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim jokes As New List(Of Joke)

        Using wc As New WebClient()
            For i = 1 To 5
                Dim jokeInfo = wc.DownloadString("https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/random_joke")
                jokes.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Joke)(jokeInfo))
            Next
        End Using

        ' Alternative which fetches ten jokes in one go - note the use of (Of List(Of Joke))
        'Using wc As New WebClient()
        '    Dim jokeInfo = wc.DownloadString("https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/jokes/ten")
        '    jokes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Joke))(jokeInfo)
        'End Using

        For Each jk In jokes
            Console.WriteLine($"{jk.Setup}{vbCrLf}{jk.Punchline}{vbCrLf}")
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

The [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) is needed because a WebClient should be disposed of after use to clear up system resources. (You could use the equivalent `Try`...`Finally` with `wc.Dispose()` instead.)

Comment: if i have to convert it to list then i can use this right!! Dim jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JObject)(res).Root.ToList()

Comment: @Riya What do you want to do with the data when it has been retrieved from the server?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you showed is invalid. Datatable is expecting array of Object , so the JSON should look like below :

`[{"id":130,"type":"general","setup":"test?","punchline":"test."}]`

Comment: @Akshay Gaonkar Yes, you can. There might be some conversion issues when the JSON contains some specific Types, or some Types might be wrongly identified if the first in the array is null. With simple objects that use common Types and non-null property values, the deserialization produces the expected results.

Comment: @tushar, Is there a way to convert it to Array?